# is there a way to form a dataframe from a tabulated from single list of data?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have copied a table from a webpage and when I paste it to a text file (or excel) the table a list of values.
here is the example list.

```
['1', '42', 'Konya', '40.838', '42', '62', 'Tunceli', '7.582']
```

I want the
0th item on column 1
1st item on column 2
3th item on column 3
4th item on column 4

## Below is a long way of doing it( i assume)

```
import pandas as pd
mylist=['1', '42', 'Konya', '40.838', '42', '62', 'Tunceli', '7.582']
city=[]
code=[]
area=[]
for i,line in enumerate(mylist):
    if i%4==0:
        index.append(line)
    if i%4==1:
        code.append(line)
    if i%4==2:
        city.append(line)
    if i%4==3:
        area.append(line)
dict={'code':code,'city':city,'area':area}   
df=pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

What I am looking for is the code above but in a shorter way, I am sure someone has a clever way of doing it, just I cannot find it...

Comment: Please show an output example

Comment: Have you considered to directly read the table of the webpage into Python? For example using Pandas [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to array and `reshape`, last pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = ['1', '42', 'Konya', '40.838', '42', '62', 'Tunceli', '7.582']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(L).reshape(-1, 4), columns=['code1','code2','city','area'])
print (df)
  code1 code2     city    area
0     1    42    Konya  40.838
1    42    62  Tunceli   7.582
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use this `pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=labels)`

and using this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks) to get list_of_lists from your list

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

labels=['index', 'code', 'city', 'area']

df = pd.DataFrame(chunks(mylist, 4), columns=labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions are possible.

You said you copied your data to a text file. The simpler solution to build the dataframe is to call `read_csv` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). It takes as arguments the name of the file. You can also provide the "separator" of each element. Here an example.
Suppose I have the following text file:

**Temp.txt** :

```
index, code, city, area
1, 42, Konya, 40.838
42, 62, Tunceli, 7.582
```

**Python**:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"..\\temp.txt", sep=',')
print(df)
#   index code     city    area
# 0     1   42    Konya  40.838
# 1    42   62  Tunceli   7.582
```

However, if you already have your data in Python (in a list for example). Ismail provide a solution. Here is another one. You can reshape your 1 dimension list to a 2D dimension list. Here the code:

**Python**:

```
mylist = ['1', '42', 'Konya', '40.838', '42', '62', 'Tunceli', '7.582']
def to_matrix(l, n):
    return [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

my_list_reshape = to_matrix(mylist, 4)
print(my_list_reshape)
# [['1',  '42', 'Konya',   '40.838'],
#  ['42', '62', 'Tunceli', '7.582' ]]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list_reshape, columns=['index', 'code', 'city', 'area'])
print(df)
#   index code     city    area
# 0     1   42    Konya  40.838
# 1    42   62  Tunceli   7.582
```